# Setting up subscription on Microsoft Graph give authentication error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to setup a subscription using Microsoft Graph but I keep getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "CompactToken validation failed with reason code: 80049228.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "18c0ce19-cedc-4184-a46f-319e1a350901",
            "date": "2017-12-05T15:59:06"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that I'm using to do it:

```cs
HttpWebRequest qboApiRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions");
qboApiRequest.Method = "POST";
qboApiRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", token));
qboApiRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
qboApiRequest.Accept = "*/*";

string postData = @"{{""changeType"": ""created,updated"", ""notificationUrl"": ""http://www.somesite.com/response.ashx"", ""resource"": ""me/events"", ""expirationDateTime"": ""2017-12-20T18:23:45.9356913Z"", ""clientState"": ""subscription-identifier""}}";
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(postData);
qboApiRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using(var writeStream = qboApiRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

// get the response
string responseText;
HttpWebResponse qboApiResponse = (HttpWebResponse) qboApiRequest.GetResponse();
using(var qboApiReader = new StreamReader(qboApiResponse.GetResponseStream()))
responseText = qboApiReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I know that the token is okay because it works okay in other stuff so I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting the error

Comment: Microsoft Graph clearly disagrees with you that the "token is okay". Please include the `token` or the code you're using to retrieve it (include the scopes).  This error suggests your token isn't valid for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

What do you means that it work fine in other stuff?
Access to Microsoft Graph need to subscribe a webhook you must have calendard.read.
Try checking the token using jwt.io. How you register the app. I used app level auth registering it with adminconsent. And use this peace of code to generate the token:

```
 public static async Task<GenericToken> GetAppToken(string Dom)
        {
            const string Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";                      
            string request_content = $"grant_type=client_credentials&scope={Scope}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}";
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Dom}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
            request.Content = new StringContent(request_content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await staticClient.SendAsync(request);
            return  await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GenericToken>();

        }
```

Comment: So for example using the token when creating an event in the calendar works fine

Comment: Your code assumes the OP is using both `Client_Credentials` and the v2 Endpoint. That isn't always a safe assumption.

Comment: Depends how you manage the app security. BTW i provide it as an example that works. For the question i think that he have to check the token to understand if something goes wrong with delegation.